# Elastic for multiple accounts

Tags: metricbeat

Can I use elastic.. to monitor multiple accounst in AWS
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/master/metricbeat-module-aws.html

Answer (score 0):

If you enable aws module in any aws account yes you can.